# Can't launch lighttpd service daemon

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, lighttpd

I want to set up lighttpd on my remote ubuntu server and launch flask app but I have some troubles when I use systemctl restart lighttpd

Here is error logs:

systemctl status lighttpd

```
● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-15 14:31:38 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 19104 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255)
  Process: 19097 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -t -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19104 (code=exited, status=255)

Jan 15 14:31:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Lighttpd Daemon...
Jan 15 14:31:38 ubuntu lighttpd[19097]: Syntax OK
Jan 15 14:31:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Lighttpd Daemon.
Jan 15 14:31:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jan 15 14:31:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 15 14:31:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

tail /var/log/lighttpd/error.log

```
2019-01-15 14:31:38: (log.c.164) server started
2019-01-15 14:31:38: (mod_fastcgi.c.1112) the fastcgi-backend /var/www/landing/landing.fcgi failed to start:
2019-01-15 14:31:38: (mod_fastcgi.c.1116) child exited with status 8 /var/www/landing/landing.fcgi
2019-01-15 14:31:38: (mod_fastcgi.c.1119) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.
2019-01-15 14:31:38: (mod_fastcgi.c.1406) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.
```

Here is my lighttpd.conf

cat /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
        "mod_fastcgi",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

fastcgi.server = (
    "/" =>
    ((
        "socket" => "/tmp/landing-fcgi.sock",
        "bin-path" => "/var/www/landing/landing.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1
    ))
)

alias.url = (
    "/static/" => "/var/www/landing/static/",
)

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/static($|/.*))$" => "$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/landing.fcgi$1"
)
```

And my landing.fcgi

```
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGISerever
import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app, bindAddress='/tmp/landing-fcgi.sock').run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I found very nice python [script](https://gist.github.com/surik00/2fef149e2f1ea716d891283ef857cc00) that generates skeleton for flask app and creates a basic lighttpd configuration.

And it worked for me very nice, except that I had a conflict with `flup` library.

I installed `flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405` version and changed `python3` interpreter to `python2` interpreter 
in my `*.fcgi` file.

And another thing I want to say that I removed `118` string:

`input("Press enter to continue (if everything is okay)...")` because for some reason I had an exception.

Hope my answer will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd can do both fastcgi and uwsgi (and other protocols, too).

flask can do fastcgi and uwsgi, as well as other protocols.

If you're using flask as a WSGI server, then you should use mod_scgi (not mod_fastcgi) and configure mod_scgi with `scgi.protocol = "uwsgi"`

lighttpd wiki documentation goes through multiple options here:
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI